# Using git I want to copy the files and history from two branches into a common parent, but only changes from specific folders

Tags: git

I have three branches, `master`, `web` and `api`.

At the beginning of the project the `web` and `api` branches were created and each had it's work done in their respective subfolders `api` and `web`.  However during development the `web` branch had created a base dummy `api` to work off of while the `api` branch was under development.

What I want to do is to write all the changes from the `web` branch's `web` folder and the `api` branch's `api` folder, with commit history, etc.

```
     C--D--E--F--G--H "api"
    /
A--B "master"
    \
     I--J--K--L "web"
```

becomes

```
A--B--C--I--D--E--F--G--H--K'--L "master"
```

The idea is that commit J only modified files in the `api` folder, so since it is in the web folder it should not be brought over, commit I did nothing in the `api` folder so can be brought over as is, commits C through H never touch the `web` folder, commit K does touch the `api` folder and needs to be changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## TL;DR

You can get what you want by:

- creating a new branch name
- running a few cherry-pick commands
- swapping out your old `master` for your new branch, or using `git merge --ff-only`.

## Long

You can almost, but not quite, do just what you asked to do.  To understand what you *can* do, and *why*, and *how to do that and get results you will like*, read on.

Git is all about commits.  Commits *are* the history, in a Git repository.  Your drawings in your question are a very good start!

Every commit has a unique hash ID, which we can represent more workably using single uppercase letters (just as you did) as long as we don't try to draw very many of them (because we'll run out of letters).  Each commit also has two parts: data, holding a full snapshot of every file, and metadata, or information *about* the commit itself: who made it, when, why (log message), and so on.  No part of either the metadata or the data can ever be *changed:* a commit is frozen for all time once it's made.

Importantly, part of the metadata in each commit is the raw hash ID of the *previous* commit.  This means that the link from commit `B` back to commit `A` can never be changed either.  (It's actually a one-way arrow, but drawing these arrows gets annoying so a line between `A` and `B` is OK: just remember that it is actually attached to `B` and points backwards to `A`.)

Since the "before" / current picture has `B` pointing back to `A`, and `C` pointing back to `B`, the new picture *must* have this same setup.  And it does:

> ```
> A--B--C
> ```

However, the old setup has `I` pointing back to `B`, so the new picture can't have `I` point to `C`.  We'll need to *copy* `I` to a new `I'`:

```
A--B--C--I'
```

To do that, we can start by creating a branch name that points to existing commit `C`:

```
git checkout -b rewrite <hash-of-C>
```

(where you get the hash of commit `C` from `git log`, and use the mouse or whatever to cut and paste it in).  This gives us:

```
       D--E--F--G--H  <-- api
      /
     C   <-- rewrite (HEAD)
    /
A--B   <-- master
    \
     I--J--K--L   <-- web
```

Note that all we did was add a new *branch name* pointing to commit `C`.  Since this is our own repository, we can create, destroy, move, or even [fold-spindle-and-mutilate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Do_Not_Fold,_Spindle_or_Mutilate) the names however we like.

Now we want to use `git cherry-pick` to copy commit `I` to a new one that we'll draw as `I'`:

```
git cherry-pick <hash-of-I>
```

This will make Git compare the snapshots in `B`-vs-`I`, and do the same thing to `C` to build the new snapshot.  It will copy the commit author and log message from commit `I`, and make a new commit now, which will become the tip commit of our `rewrite` branch:

```
       D--E--F--G--H  <-- api
      /
     C--I'  <-- rewrite (HEAD)
    /
A--B   <-- master
    \
     I--J--K--L   <-- web
```

If there are no conflicts in any files modified from `B`-to-`I` as compared to any files modified from `B`-to-`C`, this cherry-pick will work on its own and make the final commit `I'`.

If there *are* conflicts, the cherry-pick will stop in the middle, and make you fix the conflicts.  Once fixed, you run `git add` on the updated files and then run either `git cherry-pick --continue`, or `git commit`.<sup>1</sup>

If there would be no conflicts, but cherry-pick would pick up some diffs you don't want it to, you can run `git cherry-pick -n` instead of `git cherry-pick`.  This tells cherry-pick to stop in the middle even if there *aren't* conflicts.  This gives you the opportunity to change the cherry-pick result (by modifying work-tree files and using `git add` on them, just as you would for conflicts).  Then you can finish the operation as you would if you had conflicts, and the final commit will have whatever snapshot you want.

It's now time to go on to those other commits:

> commits C through H never touch the `web` folder ...

The commits you need now are `D-E-F-G-H` (`C` is already there as we started with it).  You can, if you like, use `git cherry-pick` on each one, one at a time:

```
git cherry-pick <hash-of-D>
```

will result in copying `D` to a `D'` that points back to `I'`:

```
       D--E--F--G--H  <-- api
      /
     C--I'-D'  <-- rewrite (HEAD)
    /
A--B   <-- master
    \
     I--J--K--L   <-- web
```

Repeat for each commit, one at a time, until they are all copied.  **Or you can use the first power-user trick here:** the cherry-pick command can pick *more than one commit*.  You could list them all out:

```
git cherry-pick <hash-of-D> <hash-of-E> ... <hash-of-H>
```

This would work, but it's not really much better.  What *is* really much better is:

```
git cherry-pick HEAD..api
```

Note the two dots here.  This two-dot notation is described in [the gitrevisions documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions), but in short, it means *all commits reachable from the right-side expression, excluding any commits reachable from the left-side expression*.  The commits *reachable from* the name `api` are `H`, `G`, `F`, `E`, `D`, `C`, `B`, and `A` (in that order, but cherry-pick is careful to swap the order around because that's necessary).  The commits reachable from the name `HEAD` are `D'`—if we already made it—and then `I'`, `C`, `B`, and `A`.  Assuming we haven't made `D'` yet, we get one commit—`I'`—that's not in the first list, and three that are.  Git will take the three that are *out* of the first list.  It will completely ignore the `I'` that's *not* in the first list.  That leaves `D` through `H`, which is what we want to copy.

(If we've already copied `D` to `D'`, we have a minor problem.  So if you're going to do this, do it without first copying `D`, or modify your `..` syntax to drop `D` too.  The minor problem is *so* minor that Git will probably automatically figure it out anyway, but let's not throw extra problems in when we don't have to.  Otherwise I'll have to explain how cherry-pick uses `git patch-id` to find and weed out duplicates. )

At this point we'll have:

```
       D--E--F--G--H  <-- api
      /
     C--I'-D'-E'-F'-G'-H'  <-- rewrite (HEAD)
    /
A--B   <-- master
    \
     I--J--K--L   <-- web
```

The only thing left to do now is to copy `K` to `K'`, and `L` to `L'`, which we can again do with `git cherry-pick`.

Since you expect to have conflicts while copying `K`, you can do these two one at a time, perhaps even with `git cherry-pick -n` for commit `K` (although if there *are* conflicts, the `-n` isn't necessary).  Let's suppose that there wouldn't be conflicts, so that `-n` *is* required:

```
git cherry-pick -n <hash-of-K>
```

**Power user item #2:** Instead of the raw hash ID, you can use more gitrevisions syntax.  Commit `K` can be identified using `web^` or `web~`.  So `git cherry-pick -n web^` will do the trick.  (Some Windows shells use `^` as a special character, in which case, you either need to quote it, or use `~`.)

Let's assume that this adds a file that you want to be not-added, named `api/bad.file`.  To drop it after the `git cherry-pick -n`, simply run:

```
git rm api/bad.file
```

which will remove both the index / staging-area copy—the one that's in the proposed next commit—and the work-tree copy.  Equivalently, you could run:

```
rm api/bad.file        # fix up the work-tree
git add api/bad.file   # copy the deletion into Git's index
```

but one `git rm` seems easier.  Then finish the cherry-pick with `git cherry-pick --continue` or `git commit` as usual.

Now that you've copied-but-cleaned-up commit `K` to get `K'`, it's time to copy the last commit, `L`, with one more cherry-pick:

```
git cherry-pick web
```

The *name* `web` points directly to commit `L`, so there's no need to muck about to find its hash ID.  That's how we were able to use `web~` or similar to find commit `K`, too: the suffix after `web` says to use the name to find the commit, then to step back one commit in the commit graph.

---

<sup>1</sup>The `--continue` method is generally better all around for various reasons, but wasn't introduced in Git until relatively late.  Some commands had it earlier than others.  By the mid-2010s or so, all commands that can stop in the middle like this had it, but the old way, running `git commit` directly, still works.

The `--continue` method makes cherry-pick go on to do any *remaining* cherry-picks, when you're using one of those multiple-commit operations.  So that's why it's better here.  If you're only doing one cherry-pick, either command works fine.

---

#### We're almost done now

At this point, we have:

```
       D--E--F--G--H  <-- api
      /
     C--I'-D'-E'-F'-G'-H'-K'-L'  <-- rewrite (HEAD)
    /
A--B   <-- master
    \
     I--J--K--L   <-- web
```

Our `rewrite` branch contains exactly the set of commits that we'd like our branch named `master` to contain.

Since we control the branch names, we have a bunch of ways to do the next step.  One way is to run:

```
git branch -f master rewrite
```

which tells Git to force the name `master` to point to the same commit—i.e., `L'`—as the name `rewrite`:

```
       D--E--F--G--H  <-- api
      /
     C--I'-D'-E'-F'-G'-H'-K'-L'  <-- master, rewrite (HEAD)
    /
A--B
    \
     I--J--K--L   <-- web
```

We can also observe that the move from commit `B` up to `C` and then out along the `I'-D'-...-L'` line was *strictly forwards*.  If we asked Git to, say, move the name `api` or `web` to point to commit `L`, the way it would get there requires moving "back": from `L` to `K` to `J` to `I` to `B`, before moving forward to `C` and `I'` and so on, for instance.  That is what Git calls a *non-fast-forward* operation.

The other way to view a *fast-forward* operation is that, after the label (`master` or whatever) has moved, all of the commits that we *used to find* using that name, we can *still find*.  We might have to go back a ways, but from `L'`, we can go back to `K'`, then to `H'` and so on to `C`, and then to `B`.  So, since `master` used to find `B`, and now finds `L'` which still finds `B`, that must be a fast-forward.

All of this is a rather long-winded way of saying that we can, if we like, use:

```
git checkout master
git merge --ff-only rewrite
```

and the result will be:

```
       D--E--F--G--H  <-- api
      /
     C--I'-D'-E'-F'-G'-H'-K'-L'  <-- master (HEAD), rewrite
    /
A--B
    \
     I--J--K--L   <-- web
```

The only difference from the previous drawing is that we're now *on* the branch named `master`.

There's one last option, too.  We could just *delete* the name `master` entirely now.  (We could have done this earlier, too: the name found commit `B`, but we can find commit `B` from the name `web` or from the name `api`, so we don't *need* the name `master` to find it.)  Having deleted the name `master` entirely, we can now rename `rewrite` to `master`.

This shows us how we could have done the whole thing with a `git checkout master` at the beginning.  We'd check out master, fast-forward it to point to commit `C`, and then do all our cherry-pick commands.

**All of these will result in the same commit graph, and the commit graph is what really matters.**  The one bad side effect we might get if we delete the name `master` and then re-create it somehow is that this would also delete any *settings* we made for the name `master`, such as its *upstream* (which would normally be `origin/master`).  Any destroyed settings can always be *restored*, but sometimes that's annoying to have to do, so we probably want to use one of the methods that doesn't destroy any settings, i.e., doesn't delete the name `master`.

#### A third power-user option

This kind of repeated cherry-pick, sometimes with a "stop to let me fix things up", is actually what `git rebase` does.  The *interactive* form of `git rebase` in particular lets you change any `pick` command to an `edit` command.  The one problem with this is that you need several separate strings of cherry-picking, and `git rebase` itself won't do that.  You'd have to get the instruction sheet, and then *add* some `pick` commands to it.  It's almost certainly better—or at least less error-prone—to use multiple `git cherry-pick` commands.

Still, the option to start with `git checkout master` is attractive.  Whether to start by checking out `master`, fast-forwarding to existing commit `C`, and doing the rest of the cherry-picking is up to you.  This method has the advantage that once you've done the last cherry-pick, you're done: there are no final cleanup Git commands to run.